# Calculating Avg Orders per day using MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx, cubes, msbi

I am trying to create a calculated member which should returns the averages orders per week per person.

Below is the screen shot where the client will be looking to forecast the work load.  Staff may not work all the days in a week.

The calculation will be :  No of Orders / No of scheduled days in that week.

It would not be very hard to calculate this if the week name is in the same hierarchy of the date, but in this case it is not in hierarchy but just member of the dimension.

[image]

[image: Required Output]

This is the MDX I've tried:

```
Avg ( Descendants
( [Date Planned].[Date Planned].CurrentMember, [Date Planned].[Date Planned].[Date Planned] ),
[Measures].[Orders Qty] )
```

Comment: Share the script you have tried so far in order to help you.

Comment: I know this is wrong because there is no Date specified on the rows. Avg(Descendants([Date Planned].[Date Planned].CurrentMember, [Date Planned].[Date Planned].[Date Planned]),[Measures].[Orders Qty])

Comment: Do you need the avg per week? If so edit the title of your question. Why didn't you use the `week` attribute?

Comment: @Murty Did any of our answer's help you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier when you have week and day added into the hierarchy, but if you don't have possibility to have this added, there is different non elegant solution.

If you would assume that this member will always be used with Week on rows your member calculation would be as follow:
[image]

This will work correctly only with weeks on rows - so I would recommend to extend your Calendar hierarchy by week and day and then we can  have a chat about much more elegant solution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  This may not work for me in this scenario as no of days are not fixed.   It could be any thing between 1 to 7 based on the individual.  However if I will consider your suggestion to add it in hierarchy if I don't find any solution.  Thanks again for your suggestion

Comment: When you will have week and day added into the hierarchy then I can help you to finish this - of course if you would need my help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[avg_week] AS
  Avg ( EXISTING { [Date Planned].[Week Of Year].[Week Of Year] },
  [Measures].[Orders Qty] )
SELECT [Measures].[avg_week] ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY
{ [Person].[PersonName].[PersonName] * [Date Planned].[Week Of Year].[Week Of Year] } ON ROWS
FROM [Your cube]
```

Let me know if this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like the following:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[PlannedDayCnt] AS 
    Count
    (
      Exists
      (
        (EXISTING 
          [Date Planned].[Date Planned].[Date Planned].MEMBERS)
       ,[Date Planned].[Week Of Year].currentmember
      )
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Averge Orders] AS 
    [Measures].[Orders Qty] / [Measures].[PlannedDayCnt] 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Orders Qty]
   ,[Measures].[PlannedDayCnt]
   ,[Measures].[Averge Orders]
  } ON 0
 ,
    [Person].[PersonName].[PersonName] 
  * [Date Planned].[Week Of Year].[Week Of Year] ON 1
FROM [aCube];
```

I'd like to test but unsure how to model your scenario in the `AdvWrks` cube.

Answer (score 0):

I would first want to see how many "dates" belong to the week. That would be easy as it would be those days when Orders were placed for that person that week.

```
NonEmpty
        (
         [Date Planned].[Date Planned].[Date Planned].MEMBERS,
         (
          [Date Planned].[Week Of Year].currentmember, 
          [Person].[PersonName].currentmember, 
          [Measures].[Orders Qty]
         )
        )
```

Now that you have the requisite dates for the "current" week and the "current" person, you would need to calculate the average order quantity for these set of dates. It would look like this:

```
AVG
   (
    NonEmpty
            (
             [Date Planned].[Date Planned].[Date Planned].MEMBERS,
             (
              [Date Planned].[Week Of Year].currentmember, 
              [Person].[PersonName].currentmember, 
              [Measures].[Orders Qty]
             )
            )
    , [Measures].[Orders Qty]
   )
```

Your final construct would need to be:

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.AverageOrderPerDay AS
AVG
   (
    NonEmpty
            (
             [Date Planned].[Date Planned].[Date Planned].MEMBERS,
             (
              [Date Planned].[Week Of Year].currentmember, 
              [Person].[PersonName].currentmember, 
              [Measures].[Orders Qty]
             )
            )
    , [Measures].[Orders Qty]
   )

SELECT 
    {
     [Measures].AverageOrderPerDay,
     [Measures].[Orders Qty]
    }
ON 0,
    [Person].[PersonName].[PersonName].MEMBERS
  * [Date Planned].[Week Of Year].[Week Of Year].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [YourCube]
```